Category Attachment Pagination 404 Error on 2nd Page
I'm customizing category.php to display all attachments with a specific category, but when I click on a link for a page besides the first one, I get a 404 error. To reproduce:

Install a new Wordpress site locally.
Install the Blank Slate theme.
Make a child theme that includes the files below this list.
Upload at least 11 images to the site media library and assign a category to each of them, like sushi for example.
Go to http://localhost/my_site_name/category/sushi.
Click the link "← older" at the bottom of the first 10 images to see the 404 error (it goes to http://localhost/my_site_name/category/sushi/page/2).

style.css:
/**
 * Theme Name: Blank Slate Child
 * Template:   blankslate
 */

functions.php:
<?php
    // Enqueue the child theme
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_child_enqueue_styles' );
    function my_child_enqueue_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'blankslate-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    }

    // Add categories to attachments
    function add_categories_to_attachments() {
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
    }
    add_action( 'init' , 'add_categories_to_attachments' );

category.php (modified from Blank Slate's category.php):
<?php get_header(); ?>
<header class="header">
<h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="name"><?php single_term_title(); ?></h1>
<div class="archive-meta" itemprop="description"><?php if ( '' != get_the_archive_description() ) { echo esc_html( get_the_archive_description() ); } ?></div>
</header>
<?php 
    $category_name = single_cat_title("", false);
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'name',
                'terms' => $category_name
            )
        ),
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 10
    ];

    $category_query = new WP_Query($args);
    
    // Pagination fix, via Chip Bennett: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops
    $temp_query = $wp_query;
    $wp_query   = NULL;
    $wp_query   = $category_query;

    if ($category_query->have_posts()) {
        while($category_query->have_posts()) {
            $category_query->the_post();
            the_title();
            the_content();
        }
    }

    get_template_part( 'nav', 'below' );

    // Reset main query object
    $wp_query = NULL;
    $wp_query = $temp_query;

    php get_footer();

The nav-below template part (from the parent Blank Slate theme) is just the_posts_navigation() with 'prev_text' and 'next_text' arguments.
Troubleshooting ideas I tried included checking that I had the right query arguments (like making sure I was using the variable paged instead of page), using previous_posts_link and next_posts_link instead of the_posts_navigation(), and ensuring that the posts_per_page number matched the "Blog pages show at most" number set in the site's "Reading" settings.
Any thoughts for what I'm missing here? Thanks so much in advance!

Definitely not the right way to modify the main query on any given template. Hook to pre_get_posts instead and modify it there.

For anyone's future reference. Based on Chris Cox's answer, I was able to fix the issue. I removed category.php from the child theme, and changed the child theme's functions.php file to the following:
<?php
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_child_enqueue_styles' );
    function my_child_enqueue_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'blankslate-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    }

    // Add categories to attachments
    function add_categories_to_attachments() {
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
    }
    add_action( 'init' , 'add_categories_to_attachments' );
    
    // Via Tom J Nowell and Chip Bennett:
    // https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/361410/how-to-use-pre-get-posts
    // https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops
    function wpse120407_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
        $category_name = single_cat_title("", false);
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        if ( is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
            // Exclude category ID 5
            $query->set( 'post_type', 'attachment' );
            $query->set( 'post_status', 'inherit' );
            $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'name',
                    'terms' => $category_name
                )
            ) );
            $query->set( 'paged', $paged );
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse120407_pre_get_posts' );

